# Possible to use an associative array as $needle for in_array function?

Tags: php

In my company's code I stumbled about the following use-case of `in_array()`: *(replica of what happens)*

```php
$theHystack = [
    'id' => 3,
    'location' => 'Berlin'
];

$theNeedle = [
    'id' => 3,
    'location' => 'Berlin'
];

echo in_array($theNeedle, $theHystack, true)  
    ? 'true' 
    : 'false';
```

The documentation of [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) states that `$needle` can be of type `mixed` therefore it might be possible that this works.

To be certain I started to play around with the shown code however the result was always the same.

> All results were **false**

The scenario was actually `!in_array()` thus it should return always `true`.

**Question:**

Is there a way of creating such a validation where you could validate an associative array with another associative array?

I'm looking for build-in php functions that could do something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PHP in\_array with associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809116/how-to-use-php-in-array-with-associative-array)

Comment: Are you checking they're identical? In which case `===`, or just that the full array exists in another, in which case making use of array_diff / array_intersect may help.

Comment: @treyBake notice OP last row `I'm looking for build-in php functions that could do something.`

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm but, if there isn't anything built-in (which I'm not sure there is), then the functionality has to be built, in which case, check linked dupe :)

Comment: @Jonnix If they're identical.

Comment: @GentleSama Then just `$arrayOne === $arrayTwo`?

Comment: No, it's a poor example, I imagine usually there would be more than one entry in one or both arrays.

Comment: @Jonnix Haven't thought about that and it works! :)

Comment: Your code works in the haystack is an array of arrays of the same format as the needle - so add another layer of `[]` round `$theHystack` and it will display true.

Comment: I add `[]` round `$theHystack` and `in_array` works fine. Can you add an example where `in_array` doesn't work? Here my code https://3v4l.org/ajjBa