# in_array failed to check array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am making a PHP user permission system where all permission related to specific role are saved in session as like array but when I try to check the it does not true where already the value exists in array.

Here is my session array `$_SESSION['userPermissions'] = $userPermissions;`
here is the `var_dump` of `$_SESSION['userPermissions']`

**output**

```
You are now logged inarray(6) { [0]=> array(1) { ["permission_name"]=> string(11) "create-role" } [1]=> array(1) { ["permission_name"]=> string(11) "update-role" } [2]=> array(1) { ["permission_name"]=> string(11) "delete-role" } [3]=> array(1) { ["permission_name"]=> string(11) "create-user" } [4]=> array(1) { ["permission_name"]=> string(11) "update-user" } [5]=> array(1) { ["permission_name"]=> string(11) "delete-user" } }
```

I use bellow function to check array value

```
 // checks if user can delete an user
  function canDeleteUser() {
    if(in_array('delete-user', $_SESSION['userPermissions'])){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

it always return false please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PHP in\_array with associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809116/how-to-use-php-in-array-with-associative-array)

Comment: Your problem is that the value is wrapped inside another array within the one you're checking. in_array won't check inside any objects or arrays it finds, it only looks at the first level down. This might answer your question: [Check if a specific value exists at a specific key in any subarray of a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990855/check-if-a-specific-value-exists-at-a-specific-key-in-any-subarray-of-a-multidim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to work you would need to have your `userPermissions` array to look as follows:

```
[ 
   'create-role',
   'delete-user',
   ...the rest...
]
```

while in fact your array look as follows:

```
[ 
   ['permission_name' => 'create-role'],
   ['permission_name' => 'delete-user'],
   ...the rest...
]
```

in order to search for a nested value extract first the column:

```php
if(in_array('delete-user', array_column($_SESSION['userPermissions`], 'permission_name'))){
```

or search by array:

```
if(in_array(["permission_name"=>"delete-user"], $_SESSION['userPermissions`]))
```

yet be aware that the second approach is much less secure: as if the array will change (will have other elements) this will fail. I strongly advise to use the first approach.