# PHP check element present in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the form of:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["positionID"]=> int(100) } [1]=> array(1) { ["positionID"]=> int(102) } }
```

I want to check 100 or 102 is contained in the array.

I tried code below, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help?

```
var_dump(in_array(102, $myArray));
```

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question to yours few hours ago, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331887/11430357

Comment: See [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column).

Comment: how it doesn't work ?, what is the output or the error ?

Answer (score 0):

As @mario pointed out, you're going to want to use something like `array_column`:

`var_dump(in_array(102, array_column($myArray, 'positionID")));`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
in_array(102, array_column($myArray, 'positionID'));
```

`in_array` checks the direct values of the array. So doing `in_array(102, $myArray);`, you are checking an integer (`102`) against the values of the array which are arrays.